# How to launch MATLAB without a desktop in Windows

Tags: matlab

When I run MATLAB like the following from the command prompt or a batch file, I always see a MATLAB command window popping up despite the use of `-nodesktop` and `-nosplash`

```
matlab -wait -nodesktop -nosplash -r "pause(10); quit"
```

The command window that appears looks like this:

[image: MATLAB Desktop]

I am running MATLAB R2021a on Windows 10. According to a somewhat old reference that I found [here](https://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2010/02/22/launching-matlab-without-the-desktop/), `-nodesktop` has never been not officially supported on Windows (which BTW bothers me! Why would the developers add and test a startup argument, release it, and then say we never support it?). Despite that, I was wondering if anyone has a workaround for how to suppress the MATLAB command window on Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-nodesktop` option was introduced when MATLAB got its Java UI. The option starts MATLAB with the previous interface. I guess they have stopped officially supporting it, but they never removed the option.

MATLAB on Windows has never been quite as comfortable running in a terminal as the Linux and macOS versions—on those OSes, MATLAB does run in the terminal with the `-nodesktop` option, as they did before the Java UI was introduced.

If you want to run MATLAB non-interactively, use the `-batch` option. The `-r` is intended for interactive use, and therefore launches the desktop. The `-batch` option:

- Starts without the desktop
- Does not display the splash screen
- Executes statement
- Disables changes to preferences
- Disables toolbox caching
- Logs text to stdout and stderr
- Does not display modal dialog boxes
- Exits automatically with exit code 0 if statement executes successfully.  Otherwise, MATLAB terminates with a non-zero exit code.

(from [the docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html)).

In your case, instead of

```
matlab -wait -nodesktop -nosplash -r "pause(10); quit"
```

you should do

```
matlab -batch "pause(10)"
```

(I don't know if `-wait` is still needed on Windows, this is not clear in the documentation, and I don't have Windows to test this.)

Comment: Perfect, that does the trick! Seems like `-wait` and `quit` are not needed when using `-batch`